# Error accessing parent child artifact in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to access an artifact from my parent-child pipeline where the child stage keeps hitting an error that there is an undefined dependency. It will be great if someone could share some insights how can I access the parent artifact from the child stage.

The below is my pipeline:
.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - setup
  - generate-stage
  - run-stage
  - generate-config

setup:
  stage: setup
  image: dwdraju/alpine-curl-jq
  script:
    - echo version="123" >> VERSION.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - VERSION.txt
    expire_in: 30 days

generate-stage:
  stage: generate-stage
  image: dwdraju/alpine-curl-jq
  script:
    - |
      (echo "include:"
      echo "  - local: "" common/generate-stage.gitlab-ci.yml"
      echo "") >> stage-list.yml
    - |
      (echo "stages:"
      echo "  - generate-stage-pipelines"
      echo "  - run-stage-pipelines"
      echo "") >> stage-list.yml
    
      
    - |
      for STAGE in $(echo $STAGES | jq -r ".stages[]"); do
        echo "Processing stage: $STAGE"
        # generate stage
        (echo "${STAGE}:generate-pipelines:"
        echo "  stage:"" generate-stage-pipelines"
        echo "  image: dwdraju/alpine-curl-jq"
        echo "  variables:" 
        echo "    TARGET_STAGE: ${STAGE}"
        echo "  extends:"" .generate-stage"
        echo "") >> stage-list.yml

        # run stage
        (echo "${STAGE}:run:"
        echo "  stage:"" run-stage-pipelines"
        echo "  variables:" 
        echo "    TARGET_STAGE: ${STAGE}"
        echo "  trigger:"
        echo "    include:"
        echo "      - job:"" ${STAGE}:generate-pipelines"
        echo "        artifact:"" stage-promote.yml"
        echo "    strategy:"" depend"
        echo "") >> stage-list.yml
      done
    - cat stage-list.yml
    - echo "complete"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - stage-list.yml
  depends:
    - setup
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"

run-stage:
  stage: run-stage
  trigger:
    include:
      - job: generate-stage
        artifact: stage-list.yml
    strategy: depend
```

generate-stage.gitlab-ci.yml

```
.generate-stage:
  script:
    # run promote stage
    - |
    (echo "${TARGET_STAGE}:promote-${PROJECT}:"
        echo "  stage:"" promote"
        echo "  environment:"
        echo "    name:"" ${TARGET_STAGE}/${PROJECT}"
        echo "  script:"
        echo "    - echo hello"
        echo "  when: manual"
        echo "  dependencies:"
        echo "    - setup"
        echo "  allow_failure: false"
        echo "") >> stage-promote.yml
    - cat stage-promote.yml
```